# Can anyone explain this, I am trying cross Join implementation through flatmap?

Tags: java, stream

```
List<Integer> s1 = Stream.of(1, 2);
Supplier<Stream<String>> s2 = ()->Stream.of("A", "B");

s1.flatMap(v1 -> s2.get()
                   .map(v2 ->tuple(v1,v2))).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Flatmap argument need clarification.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a typo in the first line where `Stream.of` is assigned to `List<Integer>`

Regarding the explanation of `flatMap` argument:

- Each integer from the `s1` stream is mapped into `Stream<tuple>` containing several items: for each integer a string is picked from `Stream<String>`
- Thus, these multiple `Stream<tuple>` should be *flattened* into a single `Stream<tuple>` which is consumed then in `forEach` terminal operation

```java
List<Integer> s1 = Stream.of(1, 2);
Supplier<Stream<String>> s2 = () -> Stream.of("A", "B");

s1  // Stream<Integer>
.flatMap(v1 -> s2.get() // Stream<String> returned by the Supplier
                 .map(v2 -> tuple(v1,v2)) // Stream<tuple>
) // Stream<tuple>
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

For illustration, let's assume that a mere `map` is used instead of the `flatMap` (also using `List` instead of `tuple`):

```java
s1  // Stream<Integer>
    .map(v1 -> s2.get() // Stream<String> returned by the Supplier
        .map(v2 -> Arrays.asList(v1, v2)) // Stream<List>
    ) // Stream<Stream<List>>
    .peek(System.out::println)
    .flatMap(s -> s) Stream<List>
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```java
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@3dd4520b // printed by peek
[1, A]
[1, B]
java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3@5ae63ade // printed by peek
[2, A]
[2, B]
```